# Building PyQt to work with Qt5

Tags: python, build, pyqt, qt5

When building/installing PyQt (from source or using `pip`), how do I specify the path to the local Qt5 installation?

I built Qt5 from source ([qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2.tar.gz](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2.tar.gz)) with the following command:

```
wget http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2.tar.gz

cd qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2
./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -nomake tests
make -j 4
```

If I then `cd` into `qtbase` I see:

```
bin/
dist/
doc/
examples/
imports/
include/
lib/
etc ...
```

Looking at the PyQt4 [installation instructions](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html) I could not find a flag or an option to specify the location of the Qt installation.

Is there a way to tell PyQt4 where to find Qt5?

**Note:** I do not have root privileges, and need to install this locally.

Answer (score 3):

Configure PyQt4:

```
python configure.py --qmake <path to your qt5 qmake>
```